# wilcox.test usage in R

Tags: r

I would like to know if there is a difference in the values taken from measurements of a given characteristic sampled at primary `forest=1` and secondary `forest=0`

I'm using two vectors, one with the data itself (`DATA$Measurements`), and the other one with the category of sampling point (`DATA$Point`).

How should I perform the `wilcox.test` fucntion?

I'm doing this way:

```
wilcox.test(DATA$Measurements~DATA$Point)
```

But I notice that are other forms of performing this test:

```
wilcox.test(DATA$Measurements,DATA$Point)
wilcox.test(DATA$Measurements,DATA$Point,paired=TRUE)
```

Which one is more suited for testing my question of interest, and what is the difference between these options?
(Is there a difference between points for this given characteristic)?

Comment: The first proposition is the correct one for you. The `paired` option will let you apply a paired Wilcoxon Test or not, so it not connected with your original question (linked to the organization of the data).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. Which proposition do you mean, `wilcox.test(DATA$Measurements,DATA$Point)` or `wilcox.test(DATA$Measurements~DATA$Point)` ?

Comment: The one with the formula: `wilcox.test(DATA$Measurements~DATA$Point)`.

Comment: You can learn more about the difference between these two syntaxes (`wilcox.test(x~g)` and `wilcox(x,y)`) by reading what is said in the help file (`?wilcox.test`) about `x`, `y` and `formula`.

Comment: Thanks @VincentGuillemot. Would you mind to explain briefly to me what is the difference between those options and in which circumstances should I choose one or other?

Comment: Ok, I already read it, but it didn't cleared my doubts as I wished. Thanks, though. Please, answer the question and I can happily mark it as answered.

Comment: You're welcome! You'd be surprised to find how many and diverse daughter sites StackExchange has: http://stackexchange.com/sites